# Low wattage K-cup type office machine

Tags: keurig

In my office setting we are limited to 800 watts power draw.  We have a team of 10 people that use the k-cup machine and had to switch to a k130 which is awful for multiple users.  Are there any other k-cup brewers out there made for low wattage with a large water tank?  Is it possible to alter a 1400 watt keurig to draw less power (heat slower)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know anything about keurig, but as the question has gone unanswered so far, I'll give it a try.

From my experience with electronics, there are 3 ways how a low power mod could be done, depending on the details.

The first is to mod the power supply to the boiler (e.g. put an inductor in series) and hope the machine's software can cope with this.

Second: If you do have to modify the software (and are able to; replacing the controller and reimplementing the software may be required) you could implement a pwm regulation of the heating (your power line got to survive short overloads of ~0.1s)

Third: The boiler has a too small heat capacity for a full cup and needs to draw full power during the pouring of coffe (my machine does this when it has to make a large cup). You have to change the boiler (bigger one might be too big for the case), and then continue with one of the steps.

Note: If this can't be done in the fashion of “the nerd in the next cubicle does it for free coffe and no one is ever to talk about the mod” but you have to employ an external firm and need to match safety regulations, you are almost definitely cheaper off by upgrading the power supply to the office.